# using custom view "SignatureView" to capture user signature

Tags: android

im trying to have a SignatureView to capture my user's signature after they fill up a form, but my codes are not making it draw. i found this drawing codes on youtube and tried them but it does not draw anything, although the scroll lock is working. the following is the code to

the xml for the signatureview

```
<SignatureView
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:id="@+id/signatureView"/>
```

the code for the signatureview to enable drawing

```
public class SignatureView extends View {

public static int BRUSH_SIZE = 5;
public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
public static final int DEFAUL_BG_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
private float mX, mY;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint;
private ArrayList<FingerPath> paths = new ArrayList<>();
private int currentColor;
private int backgroundColor = DEFAUL_BG_COLOR;
private int strokewidth;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
public SignatureView(Context context){
    this(context, null);
}

public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
    mPaint.setAlpha(0xff);
}

public void init(DisplayMetrics metrics){
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    strokewidth = BRUSH_SIZE;
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.save();
    mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);
    for (FingerPath fp : paths){
        mPaint.setColor(fp.color);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokewidth);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}

private void touchStart(float x, float y){
    mPath = new Path();
    FingerPath fp = new FingerPath(currentColor, strokewidth, mPath);
    paths.add(fp);
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touchMove(float x, float y){
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);

    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE){
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) /2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touchUp(){
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            touchStart(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            touchMove(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            touchUp();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

the fingerpath class

```
public class FingerPath {
public int color;
public int strokewidth;
public Path path;

public FingerPath(int color, int strokewidth, Path path){
    this.color = color;
    this.strokewidth = strokewidth;
    this.path = path;
}
}
```

the java class for the page

```
public class Application_applicant extends AppCompatActivity {
private SignatureView sv;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_applicant);
    sv = (SignatureView)findViewById(R.id.signatureView);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    sv.init(metrics);
}
}
```

Comment: I cannot show the full header tag for the xml on the SignatureView as im doing this for a company.

Comment: Here is a drawing app sample https://github.com/firebase/AndroidDrawing

Comment: Am just trying to make it draw for now, the sample you gave is a little too complex

Comment: Skip the Firebase parr and focus on the drawing @WeiXiong

Comment: Could the problem possibly be due to the android version of the tablet im using for debugging? after i updated it to the latest version, the app im using uses camera and the photo does not save into the gallery anymore, and the photo preview has low resolution

Comment: hmm from what i can see, the firebase is part of the drawing, unless i misunderstand it? i dont understand how do i declare the firebase classs though, its a locked class in the sample u gave @cutiko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[my drawing worked with this, tried a lot of ways to do this signature thing but this is the best way ive found](https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few libraries I found online for this:
https://bitbucket.org/warwick/fingerpaintex/src/master/
https://github.com/AgnaldoNP/FingerSignView
https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2017/02/android-signature-capture-example.html
https://github.com/warting/android-signaturepad

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look `MyView` class in the APIs demo of Android from this link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java

You can find some demos in this project. It's very useful

Comment: I had some codes like that at first but changed to this as the codes did not allow scroll locking, my custom view is inside a scroll view, so i need the scrolling to be locked when drawing.